# perl6 - assignment to parameter

Tags: parameters, subroutine, raku

Is there a way to do an assignment to a formal parameter?

Something like:

```
sub myfunc($n) {
    $n = $n + 5;
    return $n;
}
```

Or, would I have to create a new variable and assign the value of $n to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `is copy` trait on parameters:

```
sub myfunc($n is copy) {
    $n = $n + 5;
    return $n;
}
```

See https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-trait_is_copy for more information.

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned by Elizabeth Mattijsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49353402/215487) you probably want to use `is copy`.

However, if you really intend to mutate a variable used as an argument to that function, you can use the `is rw` trait:

```
my $num = 3;

mutating-func($num);

say $num; # prints 8

sub mutating-func($n is rw) {
    $n = $n + 5;
    return $n;
}
```

But this opens you up to errors if you pass it an immutable object (like a number instead of a variable):

```
# dies with "Parameter '$n' expected a writable container, but got Int value"
say mutating-func(5); # Error since you can't change a value

sub mutating-func($n is rw) {
    $n = $n + 5;
    return $n;
}
```